# Check if pdf is up to date for git pre-commit hook?

Tags: compiling, latexmk, git

It'd be really nice to do a `git commit -m "some stupid broken commit"` and get back a refusal from git, because the latest version of the document hasn't been successfully compiled yet (ie. changes haven't been tested). The git side of this is pretty simple, just a shell script that returns a non-zero exit code. But in order to do that, I need to be able to check whether the pdf is up to date. Apparently it can be done, since if I run `latexmk` after a successful compile, I get:

```
$ latexmk -pdf -f thesis
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 30 March 2012, version: 4.31.
**** Report bugs etc to John Collins <collins at phys.psu.edu>. ****
Latexmk: All targets (thesis.pdf) are up-to-date
```

This is nice, and I could just use this in the script (assuming it spits out a usable exit code). But it'd be really nice to be able to do it without latexmk compiling the document if it ISN'T up to date.

So, how does latexmk work out that the output file is up to date? Or, is it possible to tell latexmk to *not* compile, and just check the compilation status?

Comment: I think you just want to test if there is a .tex source newer than the final pdf. In linux, `test file.pdf -nt file.tex` will return 0 if `file.pdf` is newer than `file.tex`. Of course you will want to loop through all your source files performing this check.

Comment: @guillem: Yeah, that's what I was thinking, but I kind of wanted a portable solution that didn't require me to manually list all the included files. If there is a way to find all the included files (including .tex and .pdf and images), without compiling, then that would be an acceptable answer.

Comment: I would loop through all included files using `git ls-files`. Using `bash` scripting, this can be accomplished with `for file in [backtick]git ls-files | grep "\.tex"[backtick] do echo $file; done`. Same for `pdf` files. The `echo $file` command is only for demo purposes. Sorry if this is already known, maybe someone can make use of it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A slightly better solution is to create a special initialization file, which I'll call `latexmkrc-diagnose-change`, with the following contents

```perl
$pdflatex = $latex = 'internal die_pdflatex %S';
sub die_notepdflatex {
    # Stop now, otherwise latexmk will update its knowledge of the
    # source files and not realize files are out-of-date on the next run.
    die "I won't do anything, but just note that '$_[0]' is out of date\n";
}
```

Then invoke `latexmk` with the command line `latexmk -r latexmkrc-diagnose-change -pdf thesis`. If the file(s) are out-of-date, you'll get a suitable error message, and `latexmk` will exit with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Nice. Can you explain what is going on in the first line? For others, there's a description of latexmk RC files in [the latexmk man page](http://www.phys.psu.edu/~collins/software/latexmk-jcc/latexmk-304.txt)

Comment: Thank you! I've created a hook following your idea: https://github.com/salsolatragus/latex-git-hook

Answer (score 2):

Latexmk saves hashes of the involved files (by default) in `jobname.fdb_latexmk`
In continuous mode it then loops over the those files and checks from time to time (every 2 seconds if I recall correctly).

About your hook:

It seems that latexmk updates the hashes *before* compiling. So the second run of latexmk always returns "up to date".

The first time you could use something like `latexmk -norc -latex=idonotexist jobname`.
Running this won't work and so latexmk will return a negative value.
The `-norc` will protect you from your settings file, so you dont have to use `-pdflatex` or whatever.

But only one time. Then you have to change some files again.
This doesn't protect against "it didn't compile" but "I didn't even try to compile"